# How to call a Fortran program from R

Tags: r, fortran, interop

I am totally new to Fortran and well versed with R.
I was handed down a huge Fortran program with about 30 subroutines and about 15 functions and many other lines of code.
I was told that I needed to call the Fortran program from R. I have been searching online for ways
to create this bridge between R and Fortran with very little success.
I can successfully execute the Fortran exe file from the command line and create the desired outputs.
The fortran file is called "FortFish.f"

A question:

From R, Do I call the Fortran program or do I have to call Fortran functions and subroutines separately?

From R, Do I call the entire Fortran program like this?: R CMD SHLIB FortFish.f and then use:
dyn.load("FortFish.so")

If I cannot run the entire Fortran program at once, I will post a couple of small fortran functions and subroutines upon request.
Does anyone have a running example of using R and Fortran that can share?

My Fortran code is extremely large, otherwise, I would post it here.
Thank you.

Comment: If the Fortran program running on three command line is suitable, then isn't invoking it with `system()` from R just as suitable?

Comment: Not sure if is suitable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see three possibilities:

1. You compile the Fortran program separately, and call it with R function `system()`. You will have to pass data through files, in a format that this program can read.
2. You compile a DLL that you load from R with `dyn.load()`, then you call a Fortran function with `.Fortran()`. You can easily pass numeric data (scalars, vectors or arrays), but string data is more difficult to handle. And arrays are *copied*.
3. This mechanism to call a DLL function is considered too simplistic and now `.Call()` is prefered, but to use `.Call()` you would have to write C wrappers.

I will give an example of the second possibility.
Consider a subroutine in Fortran that evaluates a polynomial by Horner's algorithm:

```
subroutine horner(n, a, x, y)
    implicit none
    integer :: n, i
    double precision :: a(n), x, y

    y = a(n)
    do i = n - 1, 1, -1
        y = y * x + a(i)
    end do
end subroutine
```

Compile from the command line with:

```
R CMD SHLIB horner.f90
```

To call it from R:

```
dyn.load("horner.dll")

horner <- function(a, x) {
  .Fortran("horner", as.integer(length(a)), a, x, y=0)$y
}

horner(c(-2, 0, 1), 1.414)
```

If you want your Fortran subroutines to print something to RStudio console, you need to do (at least on Windows):

```
Sys.unsetenv("GFORTRAN_STDOUT_UNIT")
Sys.unsetenv("GFORTRAN_STDERR_UNIT")
```

This is really a trivial example, and a more complex program will require more work, but you get the idea.

---

If your Fortran program is standalone (it has a 'program' unit and is supposed to be compiled to an executable called from the command line), and if you are new to Fortran, I would suggest to stick with the first choice, which will be much simpler. That's what the [seasonal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seasonal/) packaged does: call the executable of Census' [X13AS](https://www.census.gov/srd/www/x13as/) from within R. The executable is in the [x13binary](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/x13binary/) package.

Comment: "you would have to write C wrappers", or `.Call` a C interoperable Fortran procedure (which could be a wrapper if the original Fortran procedures aren't interoperable or don't want to be changed to be).

Comment: @francescalus Right. I have never bothered to do that, but I guess it would be possible.

Comment: I generally prefer `.Call` because `.Fortran` is indeed pretty lousy, and one is so constrained in what is interoperable with R that one essentially is nearly all the way there in being C interoperable. (Discussion in danger of veering wildly off-topic for your answer.)

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut - I tried to recreate you horner.f90 example and I was not able to compile. I have Rtools3.5 installed and on my path but I get the error message that R is not recognized. Look at the screenshots below: I have the "horner.f90" saved on C:\Fortran     Actually I am not able to add screenshots?

Comment: @Jean-Claude- Can you share how you have Rtools configured on your PATH? I have: C:\Rtools\bin\;C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin;C:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3\bin\i386; but R is not being recognized on the command line.

Comment: @Salvador R should be in `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3\bin\i386`. But it's a 32-bit R. Usually I configure only the 64-bit one. For instance: `C:\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64;C:\rtools40\mingw64\bin;C:\rtools40\usr\bin`. Also, you need double quotes when there are spaces in the path: for you it should be `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3\bin\i386"`.

Comment: Not sure what's going on but I can't make it work. I have tried many different ways.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut-- I had not seen your comment above about the seasonal R package. I would be interested in using it since I have a fortran program that compiles nicely from the command line already. I would like to to use R to run my fortran.exe file. I looked for a vignette but couldn't find one. Have you done this before using the seasonal package?

Comment: @Salvador The seasonal package calls a specific program (X13AS from the Bureau of Census). To call an arbitrary program, use the `system` function, or maybe `pipe`, but `system` is simpler if you don't need to exchange data through stdin/stdout.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut-- I am already using Shell from a visual program but I would ideally be able to open my exe from R using the seasonal package. I will check it out to see if I can find a function that does that.

Comment: @Salvador You don't understand. The `system` function from base R does precisely that, please look up the documentation. The seasonal package opens **only** the X13AS program, which is a seasonal adjustment program that has probably nothing to do with your task. It was only an example to show you some packages call Fortran code through an executable, and not by binding a DLL.