# How to compile a Fortran subroutine

Tags: fortran

I have a small fortran subroutine that I got from here: [How to call a Fortran program from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459875/how-to-call-a-fortran-program-from-r/63462583#63462583) I saved it on C:\Fortran\horner.f90, however, when I try compile it using the command line I get an error saying that R is not recognized. See screenshots below. I do have Rtools installed and on my PATH. Am I missing something? Thanks for any pointers.[image]

And this is the error I get:
[image]

Here is the horner.f90 file as well:

```
subroutine horner(n, a, x, y)
implicit none
integer :: n, i
double precision :: a(n), x, y

y = a(n)
do i = n - 1, 1, -1
    y = y * x + a(i)
end do
end subroutine
```

UPDATE:
Here is a screenshot of where my R icon properties look like:
[image]

Comment: Where is your R.exe?  How do you normally invoke/start R?

Comment: @BarryYoung- This is the path to my R.exe C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3\bin\i386

Comment: Looks like it should work.  Do you have an icon or menu option that starts R for you normally?  If so, then  try right-clicking it to get the shortcut editor, and show us what’s in the path and command entries.

Comment: @RBarryYoung- See my updated comment with a screenshot above.

Comment: The only thing that I could guess then is the R.exe is shelling out to some other exe to compile FORTRAN and that other exe is missing.  In windows a chain-shelling error like this often misreports that it is the first exe (R.exe) that is missing.  Unfortunately I do not know anything about R installations, so hopefully someone who does can identify what might be missing from your installation or configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Edit environment variable" window, it should be one entry per path, and **not** several paths separated by a `;`.

This window was enhanced in Windows 10, in previous versions of Windows you had to type everything as one line, managing the `;` separator yourself. But this no longer holds.

When you type, say `C:\a;C:\b` as one entry here, then in a command line the path will have `...;"C:\a;C:\b"`, that is it will consider `"C:\a;C:\b"` as one single string describing a path, which is of course wrong, and the Console won't find anything in these directories.

Comment: You are 100% right. All of my entries were considered as one single string. I noticed that when I typed "echo %PATH% on the command line and saw some quotation marks around all my entries. Thanks so much for your help.